# How to store dictonary on sqllite .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

In my application every object has a dictionary mapping DateTime and String. I'm using sqlite-net-pcl and SQLiteNetExtensions and I don't know how or if it's possible to store a dictionary on the db.

Here's my class:

```
 public class Addiction
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastResetDate { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<DateTime, string> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to use Text blobbed properties but I don't how to implement in the class and how to use after to insert objects. Maybe there's another way or just use another type of db or local storage method.

Comment: Here is a list of supported SQLite DataTypes: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html You can introduce another table that holds the Notes, and links back to the parent entity, or possibly serialize the Notes data and store it in a string/varchar column. Depends on your use case and how data may be consumed. First option would generally be preferable.

Comment: You can still use it with `Text blobbed` properties from the [SQLite-Net Extensions library](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/) as Text-blobbed properties have a small overhead of serializing and deserializing the objects and some limitations, but are the best way to store simple objects like `List` or `Dictionary` of basic types or simple relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normalize your database, and make another table in relation 1-n (1 Adicction, n Notes), so you can have a `List` of notes instead of Dictionary:

```
 public class Addiction
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastResetDate { get; set; }

    public List<AddictionNotes> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

You should have two tables: `Addiction` and `AddictionNotes`

`Addiction` with your properties (without the notes) and `AddictionNotes` like this class:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AddictionId { get; set; }

public DateTime datetimeNote { get; set; }

public string Note { get; set; }
```

You could also have a `Dictionary` of AddictionNotes but is more easy to handle a `List`.

I also would suggest use Entity Framework from EF SQLite nuget package